# How do I shutdown SolrTemplate in Spring Data Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I have written a Spring Boot console application (version 2.2.4. Spring-data-solr version 4.1.4) using CommandLineRunner interface.  I have wired in a service that starts up a SolrTemplate connect.   I use this to run a few queries against a Solr Index and then want to shut down the application.

When I debug the application I can step through the entire app, but when the app leaves main(), then it hangs.  I assume that SolrTemplate is waiting for another query.  Is there a way to shutdown SolrTemplate?

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "org.ihc.hdd.serviceExample.facet.repository" })
public class SolrConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.solr.zk-host}")
    private String zkHost;

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
        String[] zkHosts = this.zkHost.split(",");

        CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(Arrays.asList(zkHosts), Optional.empty()).build();
        return new SolrTemplate(cloudSolrClient);
    }

}
```

Comment: check if this is of any help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown

Comment: Spring boot uses CommandLineRunner to allow console applications.  My question is about SolrTemplate not exiting at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `CloudSolrClient` Bean like so :

```
 @Bean
 protected static CloudSolrClient SolrClient() {
     String[] zkHosts = this.zkHost.split(",");
     CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(Arrays.asList(zkHosts), Optional.empty()).build();

     return new CloudSolrClient(zkHostString);
 }
```

and passing it as an argument to `SolrTemplate` like :

```
    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient) throws Exception {
    return new SolrTemplate(cloudSolrClient);
   }
```

and then Closing the `CloudSolrClient` which will most likely terminate the template with it

```
    if(cloudSolrClient != null)
         cloudSolrClient.close();
```